Getting 409 error when trying to deploy a maven artifact manually
I am not a maven person, but I need to deploy a jar file to a private maven repository. I am certain my credentials are correct and I do have enough permissions.
The command I am using is
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=https://redacted/artifactory/redacted \
                          -DrepositoryId=redacted \
                          -Dfile=somefile.jar \
                          -DgroupId=redacted \
                          -DartifactId=redacted \
                          -Dversion=1.0.0 \
                          -Dpackaging=jar \
                          -DgeneratePom=true \
                          -X  

I keep getting a 409 error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.1.2:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact redacted:redacted:pom:1.0.0 from/to redacted (https://redacted/artifactory/redacted): status code: 409, reason phrase:  (409) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.1.2:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact redacted:redacted:pom:1.0.0 from/to redacted (https://redacted/artifactory/redacted): status code: 409, reason phrase:  (409)

I checked on the artifactory, the jar file got uploaded, but there is no pom file, like other maven artifacts that are corrected deployed.
Microsoft Copilot Chat does not provide much helpful information.

409 usually means "conflict", i.e. the artifact is considered identical to something that already exists, but my guess is that maven does not like artifactId and groupId being the same value.
You could also try to add a checksum for the artifact, with -DcreateChecksum=true
